# Weird symbols, text, and actual characters disappearing/changing in a array

Tags: c++, debugging, symbols

[image: Here is a photo of when I debug my code in Visual C++, the highlighted things are the abnormal parts, where I circled nothing is where dashes are supposed to be.]

Alright, as you can see above there are odd things appearing instead of usual dashes.

Here is my code since it is longish: http://tinypaste.com/7a115ecc

IF you wanted to know it is the Game of Life with the option to use altered rules.

Comment: When did this bug appear? What was the change that caused it?

Comment: The `Y e s` sequence looks *suspiciously* like you're writing out-of-bounds into the game buffer.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `std::vector` and `std::string`? Your error would have been much more obvious if you were.

Comment: Haven't been introduced to either to be familiar enough to use them more effectively, I have only seen vector used for graphing.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined your arrays to be of size 10 (that is, they have elements from 0 through 9), but your loops run over 11 elements:

```
char world[10] [10];
for (int m = 0; m < 11; m++)
 {
     for (int n = 0; n < 11; n++)
     {
         neighbors = 0;
         //Begin counting number of neighbors:
         if(world[m-1][n-1] == '+')neighbors++;
         . . .
```

Then, when `m` and `n` are 0, you're accessing `world[-1][-1]`.

You need to be sure the indices stay within the range of 0 - 9, inclusive.

Comment: There's a lot of repeated code as well, particularly in the functions that calculate neighbors.  Consider extracting the calculation into a separate function--that will reduce the complexity and make the code easier to test/fix/maintain.  Coding the game of Life is an excellent way to learn about edge conditions.

Comment: Alright, at the moment I am updating my code so that if m or n is 0, it will not execute the if statement:
if(world[m-1][n-1] == '+')neighbors++;

Or anything similar, should this solve my problem?

Comment: Done, but that smiley face still appears, and the 2 blanks to the right of it are there too, what exactly is causing it?

Comment: Remember, the arrays run from world[0] through world[9], so you'll also need to change the condition in your loops to `< 10` if you haven't done that already.  And don't check indices `m+1` or `n+1` when the counters are equal to 9.

Comment: Wait, I want them to go to ten though, since I have rows of ten, and columns of ten, that is why I had it at m < 11

Comment: Too fix the problem about not checking when the counter in at 9, can't I set the array to [12][12] so that is creates a buffer?

Comment: The first index is 0.  There are ten numbers from 0 to 9, inclusive.  Defining the arrays as 12x12 might hide the problem, but it's much better to write the code correctly (lest it appear on a blog like codinghorror.com and embarrass you out of a job).

Comment: I have done what you have suggested, and it still does it, but only when it used the altered rules.

The code: http://tinypaste.com/4b649819

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7483/discussion-between-legitimate-and-adam-liss)

Comment: About your latest comment I have actually been needing to do this, since I need a buffer around the grid so that if it evolves past the grid it will count those cells that are alive, but just not visible.

Comment: Anyone have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have garbage in the memory.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I also noticed that the letters, Y, e, s, was the last input, but how could it get into my array?

Comment: Why is there a smiley at the end too? It sometimes is a ace of spaces symbol or other things like that too.

Comment: @Legitimate: The possible reasons could be use of uninitialized variables or overwriting the bounds of memory, or some sort of memory corruption.Best to run your code through memory profiling tools like valgrind and it shall point you out the problem.